# Ext.JS TypeError R is undefined TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4.2

I need to load data which is defined in local js file into a GridPanel's object. After many tries, I decided to include a Proxy in the store markup, but now I get an error indicating that "r is undefined" I am not entirely sure what that means and would appreciate some help understanding what this error means and how I can go about fixing this. To help you see what I mean, I have included below a link to JsFiddle that contains the code.

[LoadGridPanelWithLocalJsonDataUsingOnlyExtMarkupAndNativeJavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/Kobo/tqq8A/)

So far, I have not been able to use either Ext.fly or Ext.getCmp to consistently pick up the gridPanel instance or the store object on the page. And I have yet to see the data load into the grid. I would really appreciate some help with this at this point.

```
      loadGridStoreTestData: function (dataRec) {
    var grid = Ext.fly(document.getElementByName("gridPanelClientId"));
    if (!grid || grid === 'undefined') {
        Ext.fly('errormessage').insertHtml('afterBegin', 'No GridPanel Object found here.');
    } else {
        Ext.fly('logger').appendChild(document.createTextNode(' 1. gridPanel found. Proceeding to get the Store object.\n'));
        grid.on({
            'viewready': { fn: this.onViewReadyHandler, scope: this },
            'beforeshow': { fn: this.onBeforeShowHandler, scope: this }
            //, 'exception': { fn: this.onExceptionHandler, scope: this }
        });
        var store = grid.getStore();
        Ext.fly('logger').appendChild(document.createTextNode('2. gridPanel store accessed.\n'));
        if (!store || store === 'undefined') {
            Ext.fly('logger').appendChild(document.createTextNode('3. Store not found .\n'));
            if (grid.hasChildNodes) {
                var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(grid.ChildNodes);
                if (children) {
                    for (var node in children) {
                        if (typeof (node) === typeof (new Ext.data.Store())) {
                            store = node;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (store) {
            store.on({
                'datachanged': { fn: this.onStoreDataChangedHandler, scope: this },
                'add': { fn: this.onStoreAddHandler, scope: this },
                'load': { fn: this.onStoreLoadHandler, scope: this },
                'update': { fn: this.onStoreUpdateHandler, scope: this },
                'beforefetch': { fn: this.onStoreBeforeFetchHandler, scope: this },
                'remove': { fn: this.onStoreRemoveHandler, scope: this },
                // 'exception': { fn: this.onStoreExceptionHandler, scope: this },
                'clear': { fn: this.onStoreClearHandler, scope: this }
            });

            grid.store.loadData(dataRec);
        }
        else {
            Ext.fly('errormessage').insertHtml('afterBegin', 'no store configured for the current Grid instance');
        }

    }
}//,
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `Ext.NET`. Where is it?